# Deleting components from the moqui runtime directory

Tags: moqui

Every time I delete a component folder (e.g. /moqui/runtime/component/example/) I am unable to load the webroot.xml screen. Here is a screenshot for context:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjNiW.png)

I would like to delete the example application and have it disappear from the application list shown on the root moqui screen after login. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is handled better in a recent update. Basically you have a SubscreensItem record in the database mounting the example app root screen under the webroot.xml screen but the database record refers to a screen location that doesn't exist after you remove the component.

If you reload your database this won't be an issue. On a system where you care about that data (ie not a dev instance where you rebuild the db regularly) just delete the SubscreensItem record. This will remove the application from the menu and app list even if the component is still there.